# Javac can't infer type unless lambda expression is inlined

Tags: java, lambda, compiler-errors, vavr

I have the following snippet of Java code using Vavr. Type-checking fails unless I inline a parameter.

**Why can the code below not be accepted by the compiler?**

```
import io.vavr.Function1;
import io.vavr.Tuple;
import io.vavr.Tuple2;
import io.vavr.collection.List;
import io.vavr.Option;

import static io.vavr.collection.List.unfoldRight;

class A {}
class B {}
class Main {
    Function1<A, Option<Tuple2<B, A>>> f = (a) -> Option.of(Tuple.of(new B(), new A()));
    List<B> L0 = unfoldRight(new A(), f); // *
    List<B> L1 = unfoldRight(new A(), (a) -> Option.of(Tuple.of(new B(), new A()));

    Option<Tuple2<B, A>> g(A a) { return Option.of(Tuple.of(new B(), new A())); }
    List<B> L2 = unfoldRight(new A(), (a) -> g(a)); // **
}


// *  Compilation fails with: "Incompatible equality constraint: ? extends T and A"

// ** Compilation fails with: "Incompatible equality constraint: ? extends A and A"
```

Here's the method signature for unfoldRight from the Vavr library:

```
static <T, U> List<U> unfoldRight(T seed, Function<? super T, Option<Tuple2<? extends U, ? extends T>>> f)
```

and here's a link to the Github documentation for same:

https://github.com/vavr-io/vavr/blob/master/vavr/src/main/java/io/vavr/collection/List.java#L644-L671

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is that `Option<Tuple<A, B>>` isn't an instance of `Option<Tuple<? extends A, ? extends B>>` (although it is a `Option<? extends Tuple<? extends A, ? extends B>>`).

Consider the case of a `List<Map<A, B>>` and `List<Map<? extends A, ? extends B>>` (which is the same from a type safety perspective as your code). If you could write:

```
List<Map<A, B>> list = new ArrayList<>();

// Compiler error! Pretend it's OK, though.
List<Map<? extends A, ? extends B>> list2 = list;

Map<SubclassOfA, SubclassOfB> map = new HashMap<>();
list2.add(map);

list.get(0).put(new A(), new B());
```

This is now a problem, because `map` contains a key/value pair of type `A,B`, not `SubclassOfA,SubclassOfB`. As such, you'd get a `ClassCastException` if you tried to get things from `map`.

```
// ClassCastException!
SubclassOfA soa = map.keySet().iterator().next();
```

[<kbd>Ideone demo</kbd>](https://ideone.com/8Ve51K)

Hence, it's disallowed by the compiler.

If `list2` were declared as `List<? extends Map<? extends A, ? extends B>>`, you couldn't call `list2.add(map)`, so you couldn't get the same problem. Hence, that assignment would be allowed.

Add wildcard upper bounds to your types:

```
Function1<A, Option<Tuple2<? extends B, ? extends A>>> f = ...
Option<Tuple2<? extends B, ? extends A>> g(A a) { ... }
```

Comment: Oh, right, it's ```Incompatible inequality constraint: (? extends A, A)```, not ```Incompatible inequality constraint: (? extends A, ? extends A)```. Thanks very much!